# get selected multiple value in textarea

Tags: php, html, selected

I have a db_field (shortcode) that returns a string when submited query. the value from that return is AB,EF,GH (exactly this!

The second part is that i have a textarea with a list of that shortcodes. So i trying to highlight (selected) the same macthed elements.
for example:

```
$String_in_Database = AB,EF,GH;
```

Wish to have that:

```
<select name="Country[]" id="Country" multiple="multiple" size="5">
<option value="AB" selected>AB</option>
<option value="CD">CD</option>
<option value="EF" selected>EF</option>
<option value="GH" selected>GH</option>
......
</select>
```

This is how i generate the options:

```
<?php $MyArray = $settingsUser['set_disallowcountries']; ?>
<?php foreach($disallCountry as $key => $value) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $value['short'] ?>" <?php if(is_array($value['short'], $MyArray)) { echo 'selected'; }?>><?php echo $value['long'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to explode this string into array?

```
 $MyArray = explode(",",$String_in_Database);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im slightly unsure to the question, so you want to check if the user has the selected country and have it selected in the option dropdown/box?

```
<?php
$userSelected= explode(",", $string_in_database);
$allCountries = array('AA', 'BB', 'CC');
foreach($allCountries as $country)
    if(in_array($country["short"], $myArray){
        $selected = 'selected';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$country["short"].'" '.$selected.'>'.$country["long"].'</option>';
}
```

With this, if the user string from the database (im guessing that is the users settings) is the same as AA, BB or CC, they will be selected, if it is not, they won't be selected.

To my knowledge I think this should work, I may be wrong as I have not tested it though. Just my thoughts!